# Do I need an await for Xamarin Forms Clipboard.SetTextAsync() if not on UI Thread?

Tags: xamarin.forms, async-await

Is the following code (in an event handler, an OnClicked method) correct or do I need async and await? It "works" but I am unsure if it incorrect and thus a timebomb.

```
// Set a timer to clear the clipboard
if (State.ClipboardTimeoutSeconds != -1 && State.ClipboardTimeoutSeconds != Int32.MaxValue)
{
    Device.StartTimer(new TimeSpan(0, 0, State.ClipboardTimeoutSeconds), () =>
    {
        Clipboard.SetTextAsync("");         // I guess no need for await because not on UI thread?
        return false;
    });
}
```

If I need async and await, how do I deal with the fact that the timer callback must be bool but async lambdas return a Task of some type?

Comment: If `Clipboard.SetTextAsync("");` fails, would you care? If not, then having the code as is is fine, if you do, then you should attach a continuation with `ContinueWith` on `Clipboard.SetTextAsync("");`

Comment: Not sure what I would do if it failed. Put out a popup? What if that failed? ContinueWith looks like more complexity than the original problem is worth. Thanks. @JohanP if you post this as an Answer I will accept it.